# TextView ignores gradient - Android

Tags: android

I've got a TextView overlayed on a image, with a gradient which acts as a background. However as you can see in the image, for some reason the TextView is using the android:startColor colour as a solid background instead.

[image]

Gradient.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:startColor="#FF999999"
    android:angle="90"/>    
</shape>
```

onCreate in MainActivity

```
 View overlay = (View) findViewById(R.id.overlay);
    overlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient);
   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =
      new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 250);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
   overlay.setLayoutParams(params);
   overlay.invalidate(); // update the view
```

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#999999"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/statement_header" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
  />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:text="Our Story"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:background="#00000000"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#999999"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
>
< ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/statement_header" />
< View
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  />

< TextView android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:text="Our Story"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:background="@drawable/gradient"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          />
</FrameLayout>
```

No need to change the background from the code just try using this layout. And if not necessary remove the `View` child

Comment: Sadly this just changes the background immediately behind the actual text, the rest of the view still has the same problem. I'm thinking that Android specifically prevents you trying to do what I want. Maybe its due to the 2.3 ver of Android I'm testing against